# Manipulating the way we give inputs in html

Tags: html, forms, input

So I have an input tag of type text. Now when I click on it, it takes input from the leftmost side of the box, which does not look very good. So, I was wondering how to make the input taking keeping one space at left. For example, if I type "Burgers" it will be actually taking " Burger". Can anyone help me here please?

My HTML code is:

```
<form>
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder=" Search for people, 
            place, locations">
            <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="">           
</form>
```

CSS code is:

```
#search{
height: 34px;
width:486px;
margin-left: 18px;
margin-top: 6px;
position: relative;
align-self: top;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: ariel;
background: #EEEEEE;
}

#search_button{
display: inline-block;
background: url(search_icon.png);
background-size: cover;
height: 28px;
width: 30px;
margin: 0 32%;
position: relative;
right: -36px;
top:-35px;
border: none;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: You need javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, add padding to input field

```
#search{
height: 34px;
width:486px;
margin-left: 18px;
margin-top: 6px;
position: relative;
align-self: top;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: ariel;
background: #EEEEEE;
padding-left:5px;
}
```

```css
#search{
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value = "" id="nospace"><br>
<input type="text" value = "" id="search">
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yKGwVz

To check difference, I have used ids- search and nospace and added padding-left which can be adjusted based on requirement

Comment: I added padding, but the placeholder gets erased then :s